# Why is /bash_aliases creating this error when sourced?

Tags: linux, bash, bash-alias

I have a `.bash_aliases` file I've been using for a long time. Today I added some commands that are broken into multiple lines (using `\`).

Since doing that, I can't `source` the file to reload it. When I do it gets stuck. It just sits there, with a flashing cursor on a new line, and doesn't return me to the command prompt.

Initially doing the `source` command would return the following error (which I'd not had prior to adding the multi-line commands)

```
-bash: alias: date: not found
-bash: alias: +%Y-%m-%d-%H.%M.%S: not found
```

So I changed the line:

```
    /home/waiheke26/sites/www.waihekehoney.co.nz/backups/wp-files-$(date +%Y-%m-%d-%H.%M.%S).tar.gz \
```

to

```
    '/home/waiheke26/sites/www.waihekehoney.co.nz/backups/wp-files-$(date +%Y-%m-%d-%H.%M.%S).tar.gz' \
```

That stopped that error.
<strike>But now when I run `source ~/.bash_aliases` it just sits with a flushing cursor.</strike>

#### UPDATE:

I added a missing `"` as noted by Spiff in the comments. But now I get these errors when doing a source on the file:

```
-bash: alias: backup: not found
-bash: alias: OK || echo Database: not found
-bash: alias: backup: not found
-bash: alias: failed: not found
```

I've gone through the file, and I can't see what the issue is.

**QUESTION**: What is causing this `.bash_aliases` file to not update when sourced?

Here's the file (domain name removed)

```
alias bashupdate="source ~/.bash_aliases";
alias aliases="cat ~/.bash_aliases";

alias wphome="cd /home/waiheke26/sites/www.waihekehoney.co.nz/public";

alias wpsyncfolder="cd /waiheke26/sites/www.waihekehoney.co.nz/backupsync";

alias wpsync="wphome && rsync -va --exclude 'cache' \
    --exclude 'wp-content/uploads' \
    --exclude 'wp-content/cache' \
    --exclude 'wp-content/uploads' \
    --exclude 'wp-content/backups' \
    --exclude 'wp-content/envato-backups' \
    /home/waiheke26/sites/www.waihekehoney.co.nz/public/ \
    /home/waiheke26/sites/www.waihekehoney.co.nz/backupsync/public/ --delete";

alias wptar="wpsyncfolder && tar -zcf \
    '/home/waiheke26/sites/www.waihekehoney.co.nz/backups/wp-files-$(date +%Y-%m-%d-%H.%M.%S).tar.gz' \
    . \
    && echo 'File backup OK' || echo 'File backup failed'";

alias wpbackup="dbbackup && wpsync && wptar && cleanbackups";

# alias wpbackup="wphome && tar --exclude='./wp-content/uploads' --exclude='./wp-content/cache' --exclude ='./cache' --exclude='./wp-content/backups' --exclude='./wp-snapshots' --exclude='./wp-content/envato-backups' -zcf /home/waiheke26/sites/www.waihekehoney.co.nz/backups/wp-files-$(date +%Y-%m-%d-%H.%M.%S).tar.gz . && echo "File backup OK" || echo "File backup failed"';
alias dbbackup="wphome && wp db export --add-drop-table && mv *.sql /home/waiheke26/sites/www.waihekehoney.co.nz/backups/ && echo "Database backup OK" || echo "Database backup failed"";

alias cleanbackups="find /home/waiheke26/sites/www.waihekehoney.co.nz/backups -mtime +7 -delete";
alias cleanbackups-test="find /home/waiheke26/sites/www.waihekehoney.co.nz/backups -mtime +7 -print";

alias wpdbbackup="wpbackup && dbbackup && cleanbackups";
```

Comment: You never closed the doublequotes on the definition of `wpsync`

Comment: @spiff thanks for that. I was going blind to my code. Looked over it so many times, and didn't see that.

Comment: @Spiff - I correct that missing `"`. But now I get a new set of errors, as per the updated info in my question above.

Comment: Now look at your definition for `dbbackup`. You either need to escape the doublequotes around "Database backup okay" and "Database backup failed", or change them to single quotes.

Comment: So I should only use single quotes inside double quotes (unless I escape the nested double quotes). I figured that might be the issue, and have since been looking online to find into on when to use each. Seems to be working now.

Comment: Generally, use single-quotes unless you need $-expressions to work. Also, realize that there's no way to tell open-quotes vs. close-quotes in most computer languages, because they all use straight ASCII quotes which don't have separate "open" vs. "close" forms. So there's no such thing as "nesting" double-quotes, because there is no way to communicate that you wanted a "nested open-quote" as opposed to a closing-quote.

Comment: One last tip: Consider using an editor that supports syntax coloring for shell scripts. It helps make quoting problems more visible.

Answer (score 0):

The two issues were as follows:

1. One of the alias definitions was missing it's closing double quotes. (as noted by Spiff in the comments).
2. I had changed around some of the double and single quotes, whilst trying to fix the issue. This resulted in double quotes being nested within double quotes, which is what generated the errors noted in the **UPDATE** in the question. I needed to either escape those nested double-quotes, or change them the single quotes. (as noted by Spiff in the comments).